# correct tags for validating input types

Tags: theme-development, themes, security, theme-options, validation

I have following types of theme options inputs, which I need to validate.

```
$numbers = "#1234";
$email = "abc@example.com";
$simeple_text = "How's going?";
$code = "<script type='text/javascript'></script>";
```

I want to know which of following tags should be used for which of the above types? I have tried to read the wordpress documentation of the following functions, but could not find the clear answer.

```
wp_filter_post_kses
wp_filter_nohtml_kses
wp_kses_stripslashes
```

Answer (score 0):

There's much more than just those three functions. As it would be too much to write 5 blog posts (or even a whole book) about it, I'm just going to give you some reads as starting points:

- One of the rare good articles on [WP Tuts+](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/data-sanitization-and-validation-with-wordpress/) <sup>1)</sup>
- [QueryPosts.com](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_filter_post_kses/) is *the* way to read source code, if you want to avoid digging into core with your IDE. <sup>2)</sup>

<sup>1) If you wonder, why it rocks: It's written by our own @StephenHarris ;)</sup>

<sup>2) If you (are again) wonder(ing), why it rocks: It's developed by our own @Rarst ;)</sup>

Comment: _offtopic: "little bobby tables" always gets me laughing